# 'no matching function call' when inserting type into std::map

Tags: c++, stl

I have the following setup:

an `Instruction` struct:

```
struct Instruction {
    Instruction( const std::string& _opcode) : opcode(_opcode) {}
    std::bitset<6> opcode;
};
```

a struct containing a map which maps a string to an instruction:

```
class Parser{
    Parser();
private:
    std::map<std::string, Instruction> instr_map; 
};
```

In the constructor for `parser` I attempt to initialise the map with some values:

```
Parser::Parser(){
    instr_map["add"] = Instruction("101010");
}
```

And the result of said opeation is a compilation error:
 `error: no matching function call to Instruction::Instruction()`

So I am lead to believe its an error with the constructor call, however, doing something like

```
Instruction x("101010");
```

Works perfectly fine, which indicates the constructor is working as intended.

Could I get some help on resolving why this error arises? Thanks and have a nice day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`instr_map["add"]` creates a new element if the specified key does not exist yet, and then returns a reference to that key's value.  You are then assigning a new object to that referenced value.  So the key's value has to be default-constructible first, but your `Instruction` is not, hence the error.

If you want to skip that default creation, try something along the lines of:

```
instr_map.emplace("add", "101010");
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Good solution.

Comment: You don't need to use `make_pair()` when using `emplace()`: `instr_map.emplace("add", "101010");`

Comment: @RemyLebeau right, I copied from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace I should have read the next line as well, thanks :)